# XML DSIG using streaming API and Enveloping Method (Java)

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, stax

Our team is trying to apply a XML dsig to large xml files.  We have reached the point to where it is unfeasible to use DOM to hold these large XML files in memory, so we want to use a streaming API to accomplish our goal.  We have looked into the Apache Santuarino libraries and those libraries seem to meet our needs however they do not appear to support the enveloping signature.  Most of our research has uncovered enveloped signature examples and explanations.  Currently we are looking into expanding the Santuarino libraries to accommodate the enveloping dsig method.

Has anyone attempted what we are trying to do?  Or have any advice on how to tackle the problem?

Thankyou.